# Send data from Android to MySQL (phpMyAdmin, XAMPP), connection to 10.0.2.2 refused

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a problem with send data from Android to local MySQL. 
Basic info:

- I have XAAMP, phpMyAdmin, port of localhost is 8080
- In Android permission I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
- I tried set a HttpPost with different parameters example:

  ```
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/test.php");
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/test.php");
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.11/test.php");
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/test.php");
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.php");
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.11:8080/test.php");
  ```

But it doesn't work.

My code of Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText editTextName;
EditText editTextAge;
EditText editTextEmail;
Button buttonSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
    editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_age);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email);
    buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);

    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            String age = editTextAge.getText().toString();
            String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));
            nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("e-mail", email));

            try{

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/test.php");

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wyslano", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                Log.d("Log tag", e + "");
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                Log.d("Log tag", e + "");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "android_test_db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

$name = isset($_POST['name']);
$age = isset($_POST['age']);
$email = isset($_POST['e-mail']);

mysql_query("insert into login(name, age, e-mail) values ('{$name}','{$age}', '{$email}')");

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting i.e stack trace

Comment: connection to 10.0.2.2 refused

Comment: whrer you are running your apk means on device or emulator?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue.  Are you able to view that URL directly through the browser on the android?

Comment: Not sure about the java code, but your PHP is wrong you cannot mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: @jjcool check for firewall on your pc?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Nothing happens. Progress bar is a little loaded and after a longer time is: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Yes that would mean you aren't getting through to the host - you need to work out your subnets etc, what IP address does your Android get locally?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker You mean what address IP my Android device? If yes it is 192.168.0.14

Comment: Yes it looks like they are on different subnets and hence cannot see each other.  This really isn't the forum to discuss setting up your workflow though.  The root issue of the question is that your two devices (client and host) are on different subnets and cannot communicate with one another.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79118/discussion-on-question-by-jjcool-send-data-from-android-to-mysql-phpmyadmin-xa).